# "Printers" menu in xubuntu doesn't exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, printer, xubuntu

I want to print some documents from my computer.  I have a chromebook in developer mode that is using crouton to create a chroot of Xubuntu.  So I searched up how to print in Xubuntu, and ended up at [this official Xubuntu webpage.](https://docs.xubuntu.org/1710/user/C/printing-scanning.html)  On this webpage, i am told to go to the applications menu, then go to Settings Manager, and from settings manager, open the "Printers" menu.

But when I go into settings manager, the printing menu doesn't exist!  I have no idea why this is, and I would linke to remedy it.  How can I fix this situation?

Comment: This vaguely rings a bell.  I don't have ready access to Xubuntu, but I recently looked at it and seem to recall that the Printers module was missing from the settings manager.  There may be a settings manager configuration utility where you can control what modules appear in it.  But if I remember right, it was available in the main menu.  Use the search box and put in "printer" and see if it shows up.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the module you're looking for is called `system-config-printer`.  The package is available in the Ubuntu repository.  There's what looks like a related `system-config-printer-common`, which might be a dependency, in which case the package manager will find it.  There's also `system-config-printer-udev`, described as "utilities to detect and configure printers automatically".  I suspect that's why I've been able to install some distros recently and my printers magically appeared, fully configured.

Use Synaptic or whatever GUI package manager came bundled and search for `system-config-printer`, which will find all of these.

Comment: Okay.  I'll try `sudo apt install`ing them.

Comment: Yep, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo apt install system-config-printer*`. It will install all the package that start with "system-config-printer". There is only 3 packages with that name. The other dependency will automatically installed.